# Цикл foreach при работе с коллекциями и массивами

Tags: c#, коллекции

Всем привет. Начал ищучение коллекцийи цикла foreach приминяемого для работы с ними.
Имеется банальный, так сказать тренировачный пример:
Модуль element.cs

```
// Экземпляры этого класса будет содержать коллекция - UserCollection. 
public class Element
{
    // Поля.

    private string name;
    private int field1;
    private int field2;

    // Конструктор.
    public Element(string s, int a, int b)
    {
        name = s;
        field1 = a;
        field2 = b;
    }

    // Свойства.

    public int Field1
    {
        get { return field1; }
        set { field1 = value; }
    }

    public int Field2
    {
        get { return field2; }
        set { field2 = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

модуль UserCollections.cs

```
// Класс UserCollection коллекция (набор) объектов класса Element.
// Для применения foreach, необходимо, чтобы класс реализовывал интерфейс - IEnumerable.
public class UserCollection : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    public Element[] elementsArray = null;

    public UserCollection()
    {
        elementsArray = new Element[4];
        elementsArray[0] = new Element("A", 1, 10);
        elementsArray[1] = new Element("B", 2, 20);
        elementsArray[2] = new Element("C", 3, 30);
        elementsArray[3] = new Element("D", 4, 40);
    }

    // Указатель текущей позиции элемента в массиве.
    int position = -1;  

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Реализация интерфейса IEnumerator.

    // Передвинуть внутренний указатель (position) на одну позицию.
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (position < elementsArray.Length - 1)
        {
            position++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Установить указатель (position) перед началом набора.
    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    // Получить текущий элемент набора. 
    public object Current
    {
        get { return elementsArray[position]; }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Реализация интерфейса - IEnumerable.

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this as IEnumerator;
    }
}
```

Модуль Program.cs

```
UserCollection myCollection = new UserCollection();

        // Используем foreach, для обращения к каждому объекту Element внутри массива myCollection. 
        foreach (Element element in myCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}  Field1: {1} Field2: {2}", element.Name, element.Field1, element.Field2);
        }

        //myCollection.Reset(); // Убрать комментарий для проверки.

        Console.Write(new string('-', 29) + "\n");

        // Используем foreach, для повторного обращения к каждому объекту Element внутри массива myCollection.
        foreach (Element element in myCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}  Field1: {1} Field2: {2}", element.Name, element.Field1, element.Field2);
        }

        Console.Write(new string('-', 29) + "\n");
```

при работе которго, на экран выводится следующие: см. рисунок 1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же мы снимаем комментарий со строки(см рисунок 2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
myCollection.Reset();
```

которая сбрасывает указатель position до -1 т.е ха пределлы нашей коллекции, что и дает возможность выванному после этого еще одному циклу foreach заново пробежатся по нашей коллекции и извлекая ее элементы, а затем при кажой итерации помещая каждый элемент в переменную итерации - выводить на экран значение извлеченного элемента коллекции. А когда вышеописаннная строка была закоментированна, то после первого цикла foreach, второй не срабатывал - т.к указатель position уже и так был в конце нашей коллекции.

После этого автор видеокурса, который я смотрю предлагает рассмотреть работу цикла foreach вместе с массивом а не с коллекциями.

```
    int [] array={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

foreach(int titem in array)
{
Console.Writeline(item);
}
```

Затем копирует данный цикл foreach , и не вставляя между ними Reset(); - используя два цикла foreach "подряд" без промежутка в виде Reset();
Самое интрестное, что автор говорит, цитирую - "На самом деле, все массывы в C# - являются настоящими коллекциями. В C# не существует массивов - это всего лишь иллюзия и удобный синтаксис."
Аргументируя это вот чем:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

что класс Array реалезует интерфейс IEnumerable - здесь же на форуме я уже спрашивал об этом интерфейсе Содержимое интерфейса IEnumerable.
Но вот в чем мой вопрос:Почему в "обычных" коллекциях - т.е которые мы создаем сами нужно сбрасывать position для повторного проходп ро коллекции с помощью цикла foreach еще раз, а в обычном массиве, который по славам автора также является коллекцие - мы не производим этого действия? (правда в строение класса Array я не углублялся и не знаю, присутствует ли в нем вообще некий указатель? Может хоть и класс Array и реалезует интерфейс IEnumerable в нем (в классе) может не существовать подобного механизма - я не знаю)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что у вас метод `GetEnumerator()` реализован неправильно. Этот метод должен создать новый перечислитель - а он у вас возвращает каждый раз один и тот же.